# How to optimize a strategy for a simultaneous move game in excel

Tags: excel

Good day,

As homework ive got to create a strategy in excel, that will be put up against the strategies of others. It is applied to a game that works as follows;

- Two strategies are put up against each other
- You have the option to put a coin in an envelope.
- If you put a coin in your score drops by 1.
- If you dont put a coin in your score remains the same.
- The players make their decisions simltaneously then you swap envelopes with the opponent.
- If you dont get a coin in the envelope you get 0.
- If there is a coin in the envelope you get 2. Meaning, if you didnt put one in and there is a coin, you get plus 2, and if you did you and you get a coin your score changes by plus 1.
- If no one puts a coin in ,the score doesnt change so plus 0.
- If you put one in and the opponent didn't your score decreases by 1.
- The game is to be played for 10000 rounds, with the objective to
  maximize your own profit and minimize the profit of the opponent.

I have added an image of my work so far, my tracked score is currently higher, than that of a randomized opponent, yet i remain curious, wether someone can beat my strategy or if anyone has any ideas for optimization.

thanks in advance

[image]

What I tried first was to cooperate in the first round, after which i decided to copy the move of the opponent in the previous round for 5 rounods. Then I started with the thought of, he gave one in the first round and the sum of his past 5 rounds where bigger than 2 , he decided to cooperate, so we give one, otherwise we dont. Then until the end i procede with:

`=IF(AND(B10=1;SUM(B6:B10)>2);1;IF(AND(SUM(D9:D10)=0;SUM(B4:B8)>2);1;0))`

so if he gave one in the previous round and the sum of his past 5 rounds are is bigger than two we give one, if not the we see if i did not give twice in a row because he did not give enough( for five rounds > 2) then we give one, otherwise we give 0.

Here is the code for the scoring that i used.

`=IF(AND(A2=C2;SUM(A2:C2)=2);1;IF(AND(A2=0;C2=1);2;IF(AND(C2=0;A2=1);-1;0))`

The tracked score consists of the sum, of the previous rounds and the current round.

I expect to profit more than the opponent, but so far the opponent has only been a random number generator , and would like some help with improving the strategy.

Comment: This is not the best question, but honestly, the game looks fun. Who wants to 1v1? @Player() @Scott() @Master @VM300? @BigBen?

Comment: Can you post the formulas used for scoring (as actual text) that are in your image? That might help clarify the rules.

Comment: Just edited the question to include the code for the scoring

Comment: This just seems that the best strategy is to always put none in.  Then the worse that could happen is you tie, but if your opponent puts the coin in even once you win.  The scoring would need to be slightly different to encourage taking the risk of putting in a coin.  I think I remember a game similar to this in a Piers Anthony book in the Xanth series, but the scoring was different.

Comment: @ScottCraner, The scoring system was created by my teacher, and i must abide by his rules. In addition, he will grade total score as well, as the amount of times weve won, while i would win by not putting in, my score would be really low, espeacially compared to others.

Comment: To minimize points for the opponent....don't put in any coin! To minimize your own loss....don't put in any coin! Hands down best strategy is to never put in a coin. Reading the current set of rules, there is no added benefit of putting in a coin .... *ever* =). I'm with @ScottCraner on this one.

Comment: This is a take on the prisoner's dilemma.  The only other way to win is for both to always give a coin, but you are trusting on your opponent doing  the same and not trying to get the 2 points vs 1.  One other strategy is to always do what your opponent did the last round. Then you will break even on the one gives and the other does not, but you will gain one when both give.  It would be a tie game, but you have a better chance of maximizing the points.

Comment: If we consider the Expected Value, we can deduce the best strategy, without using Excel, right? Consider two events `A` (Player 1 puts a coin), `B` (Player 2 puts a coin). From all possible combinations this is `EV` with the highest reward: `EV(non A, non B) = 0.5(0) + 0.5(0)=0` any other option will end up with a negative reward.